# Parsing API result to model in Angular5

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

Below is my Angular Component with A POST API

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient,HttpParams, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Response} from '@angular/http';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {ILogin} from "../interfaces/ILogin";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  username: string="";
  password: string="";
  loginBtnText: string='Log In';
  clearBtnText: string='Reset Fields';
  message:string;
  cssClass:string;
  LoginDetail:ILogin[]=[];
  constructor(private http:HttpClient ) { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  checkLogIn(){     
    if(this.username.length>0 && this.password.length>0)
    {
    var params=[{
      "ActionMethod":"CheckLogin",
      "StaffCode":this.username,
      "Password":this.password
    }]
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };

    this.http.post<ILogin []>("http://localhost:57863/api/MyApp/",
    params,httpOptions
    )
    .subscribe((data:ILogin[])=> {
      //console.log(data);
      this.LoginDetail= data;
    }
    ,
    error => 
     {
       alert("Error ! Try After Some Time");
      }
    );
    console.log(this.LoginDetail);
    debugger;
  }
  else{
      this.message="Some Fields are Empty";
      this.cssClass="text-danger";
  }
  }
}
```

After API Call I am getting data but I am not able o use it like I used to do it in Jquery or Angular JS like below snippet

```
data.Result[0].Id
```

Since Angular 5 Work with TypeScript so I created an Interface with properties same as my result

```
export interface ILogin {
    Id:number;
    UserId:number;
    UserName:string;
    UserEmail:string;
    UserPassword:string;
    UserRole:string,
    CreatedDate:DateTimeFormat;
    IsActive:string;
    Otp:number;
    OtpdateStamp:DateTimeFormat;
    ImagePath:string;
    Status:string;
    Message:string;
}
```

But how can I use it for furthur calculation . I tried to put result in variable of Type ILogin[]

```
LoginDetail:ILogin[]=[];
```

and in API Call

```
.subscribe((data:ILogin[])=> {
      //console.log(data);
      //debugger;
      this.LoginDetail= data;

    }
```

Why cant I use

```
this.LoginDetail.Id
this.LoginDetail.UserId
```

When I print this.LoginDetail in console , its empty 
How to parse API result to a model

I am a Ap.Net Core Developer , Started Working on Angular 5 , In ASP.Net Core We Create a Model Class to hold data  , Why we use Interface For this in Angular 5 , a normal class wont work ? if do than what's the difference in using interfaces or class here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK. Your request to the API is asynchronous so your result `data` is available only at the `subscribe` function, but you have logged it after the `subscribe` function. Log in the function and you will get the desired result.
But you can still use that property in the template, because Angular detects the change of the variable and runs change detection.

```
.subscribe((data:ILogin[])=> {
   this.LoginDetail = data;
   console.log(this.LoginDetail); // is available here.
}

// is NOT available here
```

Comment: I tried console.log(this.LoginDetail[0].Status); inside Subscribe and it console it says Status is Undefined .

Comment: Try to log the whole `LoginDetail`

Comment: I put a debugger after API call and Another inside Subscribe Block , but it hit always the Debugger after API Call and after that Debugger inside Subscribe Call , Maybe that's causing the issue , it is not in synchronization

Comment: Remove your debuggers and check if you got a data in the Angular ever ?

Comment: Yes It Print Whole LoginDetail as Array of Object but not LoginDetail.Result[0].Status , Status is Undefined in that case

Comment: Can you add that result into your question ?

Comment: It works , needed to change this.LoginDetail=data["Result"][0]; , It was Under result node , not direct with index 0